# how can i combine three columns to one timestamp column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
    Hour    Minute  Second  Value
0   14.0    57.0    17.0    0.0
1   14.0    57.0    18.0    0.0
2   14.0    57.0    19.0    138.6
3   14.0    57.0    20.0    138.6
4   14.0    57.0    21.0    138.6
5   14.0    57.0    22.0    138.6
```

I want to combine the hour/minute/second columns into a timestamp index. I have a date i want to use. I managed to do this using `df.apply` with `datetime.datetime.combine(mydate, datetime.time(hour, min, sec))` but it is too slow.

Is there a way to do this efficiently using built in pandas functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is multiple `Hour` and `Minutes`, sum and add string datetime in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
s = df['Hour'].mul(10000) + df['Minute'].mul(100) + df['Second']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 ' + s.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S.%f')
print (df)
   Hour  Minute  Second  Value                date
0  14.0    57.0    17.0    0.0 2015-01-01 14:57:17
1  14.0    57.0    18.0    0.0 2015-01-01 14:57:18
2  14.0    57.0    19.0  138.6 2015-01-01 14:57:19
3  14.0    57.0    20.0  138.6 2015-01-01 14:57:20
4  14.0    57.0    21.0  138.6 2015-01-01 14:57:21
5  14.0    57.0    22.0  138.6 2015-01-01 14:57:22
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to multiply `Hour` and `Minute` with respective numbers, convert the sum to `timedelta` and add to the date:

```
mydate = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-05')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Hour*3600+df.Minute*60+df.Second, 
                                  unit='sec').add(mydate)
```

Output:

```
   Hour  Minute  Second  Value           timestamp
0  14.0    57.0    17.0    0.0 2020-02-05 14:57:17
1  14.0    57.0    18.0    0.0 2020-02-05 14:57:18
2  14.0    57.0    19.0  138.6 2020-02-05 14:57:19
3  14.0    57.0    20.0  138.6 2020-02-05 14:57:20
4  14.0    57.0    21.0  138.6 2020-02-05 14:57:21
5  14.0    57.0    22.0  138.6 2020-02-05 14:57:22

0   2020-02-05 14:57:17
1   2020-02-05 14:57:18
2   2020-02-05 14:57:19
3   2020-02-05 14:57:20
4   2020-02-05 14:57:21
5   2020-02-05 14:57:22
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```